# Why my Excel 2016 keeps using English autocorrect with another language set as default?

Tags: language, microsoft-excel-2016, autocorrect

I installed Croatian dictionary in my Excel 2016 and made it default editing language (later I even removed English from editing languages). However, when I write in cells, Excel keeps using English autocorrect instead of Croatian. For example, whenever I write "i" it changes it to "I". On my old PC I didn't have this problem.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the language you mainly write is the default - while the keyboard layout is corresponding to your physical keyboard.

Adding a language on Windows 10: https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/56333/windows-10-change-or-add-another-language/

Credit: [UlrikS](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-you-change-the-default-autocorrect-language/f9f79937-e78c-4d9d-b9e1-6c3139625c93) and *[shah](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140113151226AALT99B)*

Answer (score 0):

are you using latin languages? (english, french, spanish, etc)
you can set the proofing language of text to check the spelling of different languages within a document.

"To change the language while checking the spelling of a database or workbook, change the dictionary language during the spell-check process:

On the Review tab in Excel or the Home tab in Access, click Spelling.

In the Spelling pane or dialog box, choose the language you want in the Dictionary language list.

If the language you want is not available, you might need an Office language pack."

Comment: Ty! However, Croatian is already set as spelling language (Office language pack for Croatian is installed) but Excel still uses English autocorrect.
When I want to check spelling, Excel suggest Croatian words, only autocorrect uses English.

Comment: @Chenmunka: I checked again as hulaq suggested and in Options and everywhere is Croatian set as proofing/spelling/editing. Englis is set only as a Display and Help Language.